Symbol lookup error with Intel MKL on WSL
I have a C++ project and built it with CMake. I have no problem on Windows. However when I tried it on WSL I got symbol lookup error: /opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/lib/libmkl_intel_thread.so.2: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs. On configuration I am not getting any error.
In PATH I have /opt/intel/oneapi/2024.0/lib/.
I have:

MKL_ROOT=/opt/intel/oneapi/mkl/latest/
IPP_ROOT=/opt/intel/oneapi/ipp/latest
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

as environment variables.
Note:
WSL Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. WSL 2
I get no error or warning while building. I have also successfully run different tests where I don't use MKL.

Problem was on WSL some runtime libs of openMP does not installed when installed essentials. So run:
sudo apt install libomp-dev


symbol lookup error: .../libmkl_intel_thread.so.2: undefined symbol: omp_get_num_procs

The error means that libmkl_intel_thread.so.2 was not linked correctly.
You can work around this by adding -lgomp to the end of your link line.


In PATH I have /opt/intel/oneapi/2024.0/lib/

That is the wrong thing to put into your PATH; you should remove it.

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu

You should unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH -- the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu is searched by default and shouldn't be in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

Thank you for the response. I had them beacuse in an asnwer at a form they told that is what I needed. However I removed them as you sugessted. Then, I added target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ${INTEL_MKL_LIB} -lgomp). Yet, I got the same error.

@Savrona Find out the actual link command and verify that -lgomp is present on it. If it is, add -Wl,-y,omp_get_num_procs flag to it and update your question with the output of that link command.
